# Structured-binding and cv-/ref-qualifier propagation

Tags: c++

Consider the following example (available [here on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/KcdM36Px8)), matching the 3 scenarios of structured-binding:

```cpp
    {   // array
        auto value = std::array{ 1, 2 };
        auto & [ v1, v2 ] = value;
        static_assert(std::same_as<int, decltype(v1)>);
    }
    {   // tuple
        auto value = std::tuple{ 1, 2 };
        auto && [ v1, v2 ] = std::move(value);
        static_assert(std::same_as<int, decltype(v1)>);
    }
    {   // user-defined type
        struct toto{ int i; char c; };
        const auto value = toto{ 1, 2 };
        auto && [ v1, v2 ] = value;
        static_assert(std::same_as<const int, decltype(v1)>);
    }
```

I have troubles understanding why cv-qualifiers are propagated to the identifiers, but not the ref-qualifiers.

In the example above, I feel like it is kind of counter-intuitive that `v1` is a possibly const-qualified `int`, but never ref-qualified.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Your three `decltype(v1)` specifiers all yield the ***referenced type*** of the `v1` expression, which is `int` (with the `const` qualifier, in the third case). [From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

> If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a
> structured binding, then `decltype` yields the ***referenced type***
> (described in the specification of the structured binding
> declaration).

However, if we add an extra set of parentheses around `v1`, we convert that to an 'ordinary' lvalue expression, which includes the reference qualifier. From the same cppreference page:

> Note that if the name of an object is parenthesized, it is treated as
> an ordinary lvalue expression, thus `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))` are
> often different types.

Thus, just taking your first (array) case, the following assertion fails:

```cpp
auto value = std::array{ 1, 2 };
auto& [v1, v2] = value;
static_assert(std::same_as<int, decltype((v1))>); // Fails: int != int&
```

But the assertion succeeds (again) if we add the reference qualifier to both sides of the test:

```cpp
auto value = std::array{ 1, 2 };
auto& [v1, v2] = value;
static_assert(std::same_as<int&, decltype((v1))>); // OK: int& == int&
```

Note that, because the parenthesized version of `v1` is an **lvalue** expression, in the second and third examples you give, `decltype((v1))` will yield `int&` rather than `int&&`:

```cpp
auto value = std::tuple{ 1, 2 };
auto&& [v1, v2] = std::move(value);
static_assert(std::same_as<int&&, decltype((v1))>); // Fails
static_assert(std::same_as<int&, decltype((v1))>);  // OK
```

Comment: Makes sense. So there's no simple/intuitive way to get here an `int &&` on you third example ?